# Actions on Google open Google Maps from intent

Tags: google-maps, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I don't know how to open navigation through your intent. So when the ACTION asks user: "Do you need directions?" and he answers "Yes" it should trigger the right intent to automatically open the Google Maps with directions. But i couldn't find anything, that could open the maps automatically. Maybe with deep link?

For now I'm showing a BasicCard with a button so the user could press it and it would go to Google Maps and directly into navigation. Is there any way where you could use only voice without the button?

```
conv.ask(new BasicCard({
        text: ` If you need directions press the button bellow.`,
        title: 'Location',
        buttons: new Button({
            title: 'Test location',
            url: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=${lat},${lng}&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate`,
        }),
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this.

Keep in mind as well that this won't work on all platforms where the Assistant runs - just mobile.

Comment: Thank you. Thats to bad :(. Well this is the use case that if you are using it with a mobile it should do that if not it should redirects you to a nearest device with a screen and that would be it. Like Deeplinking.